# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ... can I get more details?

Tags: oracle

I am running a pretty complex and long query with hundreds of unions and other complex inner queries ... and I am getting `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` .... do I have a way to know which table exactly that doesn't exist ?

N.B. : the query is a part of a PL/SQL procedure and the exception is printed via `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 400));`

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00942.php

Comment: thanks but actually It doesn't provide useful info concerning my question ... I just need more verbose message

Comment: I don't think there is any other ways to determine

Comment: Are you able to isolate/output the actual query generated by your PL/SQL procedure, so you can run the query in Toad or SQL Developer or SQL*Plus? The error message should show you at which line in the SQL the parser ran into the table or view that doesn't exist.

Comment: My first step would be to get rid of any exception handler that was just doing this. You'd be much better off letting the error propagate up so that you'd get a full stack trace. Next up would be to at least use `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace` which tells you the line number of the error.  You're getting a compilation error, that implies you're developing code.  If so, you should know that it compiled successfully before you added the last few lines so you should know the handful of lines that could have an error-- don't write thousands of lines of code and then compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PL/SQL procedure compiles, any directly referenced table must exist. I'd assume it is dynamic SQL. If you are using DBMS_SQL, then you can use [LAST_ERROR_POSITION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68271). If you are using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, and you have your SQL in a handy variable, then have your code do something like:

```
begin
  execute immediate v_sql;
exception
  when others then
    declare
      v_cur BINARY_INTEGER;
    begin
      v_cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
      dbms_sql.parse (v_cur, v_sql, dbms_sql.native);
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line (sqlerrm || ' near pos ' ||
                     substr(v_sql,dbms_sql.last_error_position -10,40));
        dbms_sql.close_cursor (v_cur);
        raise;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: `dbms_sql.last_error_position` is very helpful ... thank u