# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist with huge query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-00942

is there a possible way to get more accurate error messages from Oracle?

I have this very large query, with many joins ( entity with multiple @oneToMany )

however, i keep getting

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Error.

I have no idea why and i have one by one re-granted what i think is every table in query, yet, this error still persists....

How do i find out where the query is actually failing? i have feeling it isnt even a missing about table...

i cant really share the query, but is there possible other things that can throw the same error?

I can also run SELECT on all the tables in query, tested them one by one..

Comment: In most GUIs that I've used, you'll get a red squiggle near the problem. Or SQL*Plus will indicate where it thinks the issue was. How are you running the query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ... can I get more details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292623/ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-can-i-get-more-details)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should get the line of the error:

```
SQL> select err from so_59733262;
select err from so_59733262
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

and the * points to the last table which is missing.